# iPad App showing a strange icon not in project

Tags: ios, icons

When updating an App to IOS7 I changed the icon set.

To do this, I migrated to use xcasset and removed the original icons from the project tree.

[image: icons set in xcasset]

However, the icon shown is nothing that has been added to the project.

[image: This is the icon I see]

Can anybody help?

---

Additional info
[image: xcassets]

[image: general page]

[image: info page]
It looks like stuff may be needed here - but I didn't need it for the second target in teh project.

Comment: That looks like the default icon that is shown when the app icon cannot be found. I would double-check that your icons are added to the project correctly and are also correctly included in your target.

Comment: @BergQuester I didn't see your comment, I removed my answer ;-)

Comment: As you can see, they seem to be added in xcasset (AppIcons-2).
The project is set up to use AppIcons-2 as well.
 Is there anything else I should do?

Comment: @null no biggie. I didn't get a chance to see your answer. ;-)

Comment: @DaveAppleton I am not certain off-hand, I haven't had the chance to really play with the xcasset stuff myself. Perhaps if you post screen shots of the target configuration: the app icon section of the General tab, the icons section of the Target Properties under the Info tab and the relevant files under the Copy phase of Build Phases. The target membership of of the xcasset file in the right-hand sidebar would probably be useful too.

Comment: Thanks for the help - I got it, as Jerome suggested by manually adding the assets to the resources to be included in the bundle.

Comment: That app icon appeared on my iPad recently after the last ipad upgrade.
I don't remember adding or removing anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the xcasset to the copy bundle resource in the build phase of the target.

Comment: I think that When I added my second target, the second target got the assets transferred properly but the older one didn't. I had been also advised to remove the Icon related entries in the info.plist - which I did. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This icon is the default icon for apps on ios7. It corresponds to the video apple put together that was presented at the beginning of WWDC. It talks about how Apple does design

Apple - Designed By Apple - Intention - YouTube
www.youtube.com/watch?v...

Comment: His question isn't where did that icon come from, but how to get the correct icon to show up.

Comment: True BergQuestor but at least that tells me where it comes from which was a puzzle.

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry. Just upload to App Store. It will work. I had the same worry and uploaded the app to appstore. It is showing the app icon now after installing from appstore!

Comment: Apreciate this - but did not want to risk it. Jerome's answer did the trick.